# Scala Syntax Partial

Tags: scala

When I create a partial function, why can't I immediately invoke it?

Both res6 and res8 are the same type (function1) so I'm not sure how come res7 works (immediately invoking it) and what would be res9 fails

```
scala> ((x: Int) => x + 1)
res6: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> ((x: Int) => x + 1)(1)
res7: Int = 2

scala> def adder(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
adder: (a: Int, b: Int)Int

scala> adder(1, _: Int)
res8: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> adder(1, _: Int)(1)
<console>:12: error: Int does not take parameters
       adder(1, _: Int)(1)
                       ^

scala> (adder(1, _: Int))(1)
res10: Int = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've just found one of the little Scala compiler quirks.

I don't know how this case is implemented exactly in the parser, but from the looks of it Scala thinks you are invoking a function with multiple parameter lists (of the form `f(...)(...)`). Thus you need to explicitly surround the partially applied function with brackets here, so that compiler could disambiguate between `f()()` and `f(_)()` forms. In `res8` you don't have any parameters following the function, so there is no ambiguity. Otherwise, Scala would require you to follow the function with underscore if you ommit parameter list: `f _` or `f() _`.

You can still immediately apply that function as you show in `res10`.

Answer (score 1):

```
adder(1, _: Int)
```

This is caused by scala compiler will expand it to:

```
((x: Int) => adder(1, x)(1))
```

and this is caused by the compiler can't infer the wildcard's context, like:

```
_ + _
scala> _ + _
<console>:17: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1, x$2) => x$1.$plus(x$2))
 _ + _
   ^
<console>:17: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1: <error>, x$2) => x$1.$plus(x$2))
   _ + _
```

so you can do it with context bounds, as your way:

```
(adder(1, _: Int))(1)
```

it will be expanded like:

```
((x: Int) => adder(1, x))(1)
```